# Java - How to know if a printer is a network printer?

Tags: java, networking, printing

I know how to list all the printers installed in the OS:

```
PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
```

but a `PrintService` does not have information about the printer location.

Is there any way to see if a printer is a network printer? or has a share name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 years later...

I used **[JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna)** and [this extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476914/how-can-i-get-a-printers-make-and-model-in-java/34322066#34322066) to add `PRINTER_INFO_2` support.

Also, I used `WinspoolExt.PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL | WinspoolExt.PRINTER_ENUM_CONNECTIONS` as the flags.

`PRINTER_INFO_2.pShareName` and `PRINTER_INFO_2.pServerName` have the information I needed.